# How to show different logo color when scrolling down in navbar in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have logo(text), phone number and some links in navbar, when I scrolldown I want to change that color of that logo, how can I do it in js.

```html
<nav class="main-nav transparent stick-fixed js-transparent">
  <div class="full-wrapper relative clearfix container">
    <!-- Logo ( * your text or image into link tag *)-->
    <div class="nav-logo-wrap local-scroll">
      <a href="<?= base_url('/') ?>">
        <p style="font-family: UniversityW01-Roman;color:#fff;margin-top:37px; font-size: 49px;">Logo Here</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-contact"><a href="tel:+12156464" style="color:#ffffff; font-size: 18px;"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> Number here</a></div>
    <!-- Main Menu-->
    <div class="inner-nav desktop-nav">
      <ul class="clearlist">
        <li><a href="/" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li class="slash">/</li>
        <li><a href="<?= base_url('about') ?>">About</a></li>
        <li class="slash">/</li>
        <li><a href="<?= base_url('fleet') ?>">Fleet</a></li>
        <li class="slash">/</li>
        <li><a href="<?= base_url('tours') ?>">Tours</a></li>
        <li class="slash">/</li>
        <li><a href="<?= base_url('contact') ?>">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="slash">/</li>
        <li><a href="<?= base_url('admin') ?>">Login</a></li>

        <!-- End Search-->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End Main Menu-->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: please provide css.

Comment: hi how to share this css file with you

Comment: does below answers , answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

are you searching for this ? https://codepen.io/eighthday/pen/MKqBjX

```js
function logoSwitch () {
  $('.altLogo').each(function() {
    $(this).css('top',
      $('.startLogo').offset().top -  $(this).closest('.row').offset().top
    );
  });
};

$(document).scroll(function() {logoSwitch();});

logoSwitch();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}
.row {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
}

.startLogo {
  position: fixed;
}

.altLogo {
  position: absolute;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

.black {
  color: #1d1d1d;
}

.grey {
  background: #ccc;
}

.blue {
  background: skyBlue
}

#scroll {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row grey ">
<h1 class="logo black startLogo">Vertical Logo</h1> 
</div>

<div class="row blue">
<h1 class="logo white altLogo">Vertical Logo</h1> 
</div>

<div id="scroll">SCROLL <Br/> &#8595;</div>
```

Comment: just give the link in comment. There is no need to add separate answer.

Comment: I don't have enough point to comment here, and only link of codepen is not acceptable solution section may be you know that.

Comment: Okay. I have figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (scroll > 300) {
     $(".logo").css("color" , "#fff");
   }

   else{
    $(".logo").css("color" , "coral");   
   }
  })
})
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:1000px;
}
.black{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  background:#333;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  
}
.black ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
}

.black ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  color:red;
}

.blue{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="black">
  <ul>
    <li class="logo">Logo</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```